# Bootstrap navbar width issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have annoying problem in my bootstrap menu, when I added " navbar Form" in the menu the width of the menu become larger than the width of the screen in mobile mode (when I decrease browser width for example, or when I open the page on the mobile). Knowing that the issue disappear whenever I remove the form code.
See my code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<li>
          <form class="navbar-form" role="search" action="ActionPages\index_Search_Action.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
         <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="font-size:large"></span></div>
                    <input type="text" name="txtSearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                   </div>
        </form>
      </li>
```

What Should I do?

Comment: have you tried giving the form a 100% width or `col-sm-12` class

Comment: @Ryad using 100% width helped small. The issue gone away unless I change the direction of content (direction:rtl)

Answer (score 1):

We would need to see the rest of the DOM for the nav bar that you used to fully know the issue, but you can try this, it should work:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li>
          <form class="navbar-form" role="search" action="ActionPages\index_Search_Action.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="font-size:large"></span></div>
              <input type="text" name="txtSearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>
          </form>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Using this will mean I should change most of the design. anyway I will test this later, thank you so much.

Comment: If you don't want a full nav-bar, that collapses, you can remove most of the un-needed elements from the snippet. Try this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/31356/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try removing your `<li>` tags. These tags are intended to be used inside some kind of list.

Comment: No, this is not helping. Thanks anyway